# How to use annotation style used on The Atlantic's article, "The Host" by David Foster Wallace

Tags: html, css

[This is what I want](https://38.media.tumblr.com/e35167d2556a8a6416ae68f9b6c2b514/tumblr_inline_notlshs8W31qz6f4b_540.gif) to replicate on my website for students. I am new to coding and I have tried to copy, paste a chunk of the source code, but nothing seems to work.

[Here is a link to the article itself](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2005/04/host/303812/#annotation1).

Any help is appreciated. If this is considered spam, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can thank me later ;)

```js
(function() { (function() { $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".annotation-link").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var annotation_id = $(this).data("annotation");
        $(".annotation-link[data-annotation=" + annotation_id + "]").toggleClass("active");
        $(".annotation[data-annotation=" + annotation_id + "]").toggleClass("active").attr("style", "");
    });
});
 }).call(this); }).call(this);
```

```css
.article-body .annotation-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px; }
  .article-body .annotation-link:after {
    content: " [+]";
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle; }
    @media only print {
      .article-body .annotation-link:after {
        counter-increment: footnotes;
        content: " [" attr(data-annotation) "]"; } }
.article-body .annotation-link.active:after {
  content: " [-]"; }
  @media only print {
    .article-body .annotation-link.active:after {
      content: " [" attr(data-annotation) "]"; } }
.article-body .annotation-link:hover {
  color: #000; }
.article-body .annotation {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 0.94444444444em;
  display: none;
  color: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-radius: 4px; }
  @media only print {
    .article-body .annotation {
      display: block !important;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-right: 1em;
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      border-radius: 0;
      border: 1px solid #333; }
      .article-body .annotation .annotation {
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 0; }
      .article-body .annotation:before {
        content: "[" attr(data-annotation) "] "; } }
.article-body .annotation .blockquote {
  margin: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  display: block; }
.article-body .annotation.active,
.article-body .annotation:target {
  display: block !important; }
.article-body .annotation-link.orange {
  background-color: #f9bd4e; }
.article-body .annotation.orange {
  background-color: rgba(249, 189, 78, 0.55); }
.article-body .annotation-link.green {
  background-color: #50cea8; }
.article-body .annotation.green {
  background-color: rgba(80, 206, 168, 0.55); }
.article-body .annotation-link.red {
  background-color: #f47453; }
.article-body .annotation.red {
  background-color: rgba(244, 116, 83, 0.55); }
.article-body .annotation-link.purple {
  background-color: #c493ff; }
.article-body .annotation.purple {
  background-color: rgba(196, 147, 255, 0.55); }
.article-body .annotation-link.pink {
  background-color: #e1708c; }
.article-body .annotation.pink {
  background-color: rgba(225, 112, 140, 0.55); }
.article-body .annotation-link.blue {
  background-color: #3eabb4; }
.article-body .annotation.blue {
  background-color: rgba(62, 171, 180, 0.55); }
.article-body .annotation-link.chartreuse {
  background-color: #abdb42; }
.article-body .annotation.chartreuse {
  background-color: rgba(171, 219, 66, 0.55); }

/*# sourceMappingURL=annotations.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='article-body'>

<a class="purple annotation-link" data-annotation="5" href="#annotation5" data-omni-click="r'article',r'link',r'9',r'303812'">peaking</a>

<span class="purple annotation" data-annotation="5" id="annotation5" style=""> <span class="purple1">'Mondo's lay explanation of what peaking is consists of pointing at the red area to the right of the two volumeters' bobbing needles on the mixing board: "It's when the needles go into the red." The overall mission, apparently, is to keep the volume and resonance of a host's voice high enough to be stimulating but not so high that they exceed the capacities of an AM analog signal or basic radio receiver. <a class="purple annotation-link" data-annotation="6" href="https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2005/04/host/303812/#annotation6" data-omni-click="r'article',r'link',r'10',r'303812'">One reason</a><span class="purple annotation" data-annotation="6" id="annotation6" style="display: none;"> <span class="purple1">Another reason is mike processing, which evens and fills out the host's voice, removing raspy or metallic tones, and occurs automatically in Airmix. There's no such processing for the callers' voices. </span> </span> why callers' voices sound so much less rich and authoritative than hosts' voices on talk radio is that it is harder to keep telephone voices from peaking. </span> </span></div>
```